# running eval command from bash script

Tags: xcode, bash, perl, shell, unix

I have a script in which I am trying to run a perl script that exports Xcode build settings to the context of the session. But for some reason, when I run the below script, the `$BUILD_DIR` is always empty. But when I run the same set of commands from the command line, it works perfectly fine. Am I missing something?

```
#!/bin/sh

{
    yes | ./perlScript.pl;
    runPerl=`perl perlScript.pl`
    eval $runPerl;
    echo Build path is $BUILD_DIR;
}

echo all operations are done!
```

The perl script, as a reference

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open(FH, "xcodebuild -project MyProj.xcodeproj -scheme MyScheme -showBuildSettings|");
while(<FH>) {
 if (/\s*(\w+)\s*=\s*(.*)$/) { # Search for <key> = <value>
 $key = $1; $value = $2;
 print "export $key='$value'\n";
 }
}
close(FH);
```

Comment: Debugging usually have enlightening effect.

Comment: Your Perl script doesn't do anything you couldn't do from the `bash` script itself. There's no need for `eval` here, assuming you are actually using `bash` and not some other POSIX-compatible shell.

Answer (score 0):

Environment inheritance ?  When you start your sh script it does not know anything about $BUILD_DIR and it will not know even after that because the sourced pl script will inherit environment of your sh script.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `source scriptname` command to have everything take place in the context of the current shell, rather than a subshell. (You can also use `.` as an alias for source, e.g. `. scriptname`.)